# Tauri: Convert listen(eventName, handler) to an Observable to be handled in Angular

Tags: events, rust, rxjs, observable, tauri

If you're using JS, the documentation works well. But in case of angular I would prefer to handle observables instead of promises. The problem is that this kind of promise has a handler. I tried many approaches listed below but nothing seems to work.

```
from(listen("click", v => v))
```

```
let x = async() => listen("click", v => v)
```

Does anyone know how to convert this kind of event to an `Observable`?

The response is always this:

```
function () {
    var self = this,
        args = arguments;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var gen = fn.apply(self, args);

      function _next(value) {
        asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value);
      }

      function _throw(err) {
        asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err);
      }

      _next(undefined);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create an `Observable` yourself with `new Observable`.

```js
const obs$ = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  const unlisten = listen("click", v => subscriber.next(v))

  return async () => {  
    (await unlisten)()
  }
})
```

Inside the callback, we `listen` to the events and pass each event to `subscriber.next(v)`.

We also want to call `unlisten` when the `Observable` is unsubscribed to clean up the event listener. We can do that by returning the `unlisten`. The function returned by the callback will be called when the `Observable` is unsubscribed.

Comment: Your solution works with some modification, just I want to make sure that returning si the right way to do it 
```
return from(unlisten).subscribe()
```

Comment: @Jean-PaulAbi-Ghosn - I edited my answer. Its probably better to `await` this Promise

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tobias S., I was able to create those 2 functions and reuse them in all my services.

```
import {from, map, Observable, ObservableInput, ObservedValueOf} from "rxjs";
import {emit, listen, Event} from "@tauri-apps/api/event";

export function tauriListen(listenerName: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<any>((subscriber) => {
        // return from(listen(listenerName, v => subscriber.next(v))).subscribe()
        const unlisten = listen(listenerName, v => subscriber.next(v))
        return async () => {
            (await unlisten)()
        }
    }).pipe(
        map((response: Event<any>) => response.payload)
    );
}

export function tauriEmit(emitterName: string, payload: any) {
    return from(emit(emitterName, payload));
}
```